# Grouping and sorting an array

Tags: php

I have an array

```
Array

(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner1 
            [cnt] => 0
            [ST_STATUS] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner1 
            [cnt] => 3675
            [ST_STATUS] => No Run
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner2
            [cnt] => 416
            [ST_STATUS] => No Run
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner3
            [cnt] => 273
            [ST_STATUS] => No Run
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 10/1/2011 
            [OWNER] => owner2
            [cnt] => 14
            [ST_STATUS] => No Run
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 10/10/2011
            [OWNER] => owner3
            [cnt] => 1
            [ST_STATUS] => Failed
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 10/10/2011
            [OWNER] => owner3
            [cnt] => 11
            [ST_STATUS] => No Run
        )

}
```

I want to group an array by OWNER FIELD that is i should return an array which is grouped

by OWNER

values .
like this

```
array( [0] => Array

        (

            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner1 
            [cnt] => 0
            [ST_STATUS] => 
        ),


 [1] => Array

        (

            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner1 
            [cnt] => 0
            [ST_STATUS] => 
        )

 [2] => Array
        (


            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner1 
            [cnt] => 0
            [ST_STATUS] => 
        ),



 [3] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner2 
            [cnt] => 0
            [ST_STATUS] => 
        ),


 [4] => Array
        (
            [sub] => 
            [OWNER] => owner2 
            [cnt] => 0
            [ST_STATUS] => 
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$temp = $result = array();
foreach ($array as $sub) { // Put original array into OWNER groups
  $temp[$sub['OWNER']][] = $sub;
}
ksort($temp); // Sort by OWNER name
foreach ($temp as $group) { // Put sorted array back into correct format
  foreach ($group as $sub) {
    $result[] = $sub;
  }
}
unset($temp);
print_r($result);
```

...or the alternative approach...

```
// create an array for the columns
$owner = array();
foreach ($array as $rowid => $rowdata) {
  $owner[$rowid] = $rowdata['OWNER'];
}
// Sort it
array_multisort($owner,SORT_ASC,$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

easy as pie

```
$originalArray = your_value;
$groupedArray = array();
foreach($originalArray as $value){
    $groupedArray[$value['OWNER']][] = $value 
}
```

and later you have $groupedArray with all groups and their values as arrays